# EXECUTE AS and OPENROWSET bulkload

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've created a stored procedure as one user who has admin privileges and included

```
WITH EXECUTE AS SELF
```

Then i'm trying to execute the stored procedure with a user who has no privileges, attempting to impersonate the user who is an admin.

But it errors back saying the user does not have the privileges to use bulk load.

Anyway round this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to find the ID of the principal that is "self" for a procedure:

```
select  execute_as_principal_id 
from    sys.sql_modules 
where   object_id = object_id('YourProcedureName')
```

For me, that's `null` most of the time, which seems like it shouldn't work.  Try this instead:

```
WITH EXECUTE AS 'UserWhoHasAdminRights'
```

or to execute as DBO:

```
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
```

Answer (score 0):

I supposed the admin user can execute the proc, right?

Can you show how you are doing the call?

Because EXECUTE AS SELF means execute as user calling the proc, so you would have to do something like `EXECUTE AS USER = 'user_with_permission'` before calling the proc

Comment: From MSDN: "EXECUTE AS SELF is equivalent to EXECUTE AS user_name, where the specified user is the person creating or altering the module. The actual user ID of the person creating or modifying the modules is stored in the execute_as_principal_id column in the sys.sql_modules or sys.service_queues catalog view."

Comment: that's what I meant. If he is calling the proc with his own user, the execute as self would be the same as execute as his_user. which would fail. Thats why I asked how he is doing the impersonation to the admin user

Comment: From the post, "I've created a stored procedure as one user who has admin privileges"  He's expecting "as self" to refer to that user, and it should.  But for some reason it doesn't work like that.

Comment: The admin user can execute the stored procedure yes.
I'm calling it in vba